# Selenium Webdriver-Unable to find any element inside second child iframe(having dynamic name)

Tags: iframe, selenium-webdriver

![**Child frames are having dynamic name/id**][1]

**Browser-IE8**

I have to find a prompt box inside the second child iframe.

the parent iframe is having fixed id.Able to find element inside that
using driver.switchTo().frame(0)
The first child iframe is having dynamic name/id.
`cframe_ms_id59` .Only last part changes.i.e. `id59`
I am able to find this element using `xpath`
**driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id, 'cframe_ms']"))**

But my prompt box having a textbox resides in the **Second Child iframe** **(green color )****having dynamic name/id.**I am not able to enter inside this iframe** and not able to find any element inside that.

```
Plz suggest some solution
```

**Here is the HTML code structure-**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <body>
    <iframe id="adviseDesktop" src="...//path">**//Parent Iframe-Able to 
      |                       find this iframe using          driver.switchto().frame(0)**
      |------ <html>
              <head>
               <body class="desktopbody" id="desktop body">
                |                   ------code----
                |                   ------------code---
                |------------  <iframe name="cframe_ms_id59" id="cframe_ms_id59" src='abc.jsp">**//first child iframe last part of name and id changing dynamically**
                |                    -------------
                |                     ------------
                |------------- <table class="mdiwindow" id =dwindow_ms_99"
                                        |            <tr height="100%">
                                        |--- <td class="mdiwindowContent">
                                               |-- <iframe name="cframe_ms_id54" id="cframe_ms_id54" src="/xysx/modal/desktop/main.jspx">**//Second child iframe  last part of name and id changing dynamically.IFrame where our text box of prompt box resides**                                  |
                                                      |------------
                                                      | -----------------
                                                      |-----  <input name=balance_val class="x27" id="balance_val>**//textbox**
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the html code.

Comment: Provided the HTML code structure..

Comment: Sakshi-Screenshot didnt get attach because of some  issue.However shared HTML code

Answer (score 1):

i think it's usefull for you.
get xpath from child frame before type this code line -

> driver.switchTo().frame(1);

than you switch to child frame so you get easily xpath or class/id of child frame elements.

back to default frame type this code line -

> driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

where is your attached screenshot ??

Comment: Hi Kaushik,This approach is not working since I am not able to switch the second Child iframe.Plz have a look at HTML Code to get more clear idea

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the HTML, you seem to have an iframe inside an iframe inside an iframe which contains the input you want to find. For this you need to switch into frames sequentially. See below for C# code.

```
var textbox = driver.SwitchTo()
                .Frame("adviseDesktop")    //control in frame with id="adviseDesktop"
                .SwitchTo()
                .Frame(1)                  //control in frame with id="cframe_ms_id54"
                .FindElement(By.Id("balance_val")); //input with id="balance_val"
```

Once you are done with the actions in that frame, you need to switch out to default content.

```
    //control in frame with id="cframe_ms_id54"
    _driver.SwitchTo()
                     .ParentFrame() //control in frame with id="adviseDesktop"
                     .SwitchTo()
                     .DefaultContent(); //control in topmost body of the document
```

Comment: Hi user903039.Please look again at HTML code structure.The third iframe with id="cframe_ms_id54 is not inside second iframe.Its under parent iframe having id=adviseDesktop.I also checked with your code.but its not working because third iframe is under parent iframe adviseDesktop

Comment: @Aakash, I corrected the code in my answer above to reflect your comments. However, I would suggest you speak to the developers and see if they can put a static id on all frames, in fact, at least all elements that automation tests need to interact with, to make your test code reliable.